# C++ Structure member points to another memory location after receiving original address as member function argument

Tags: c++, pointers, graph, structure, memory-address

I am trying to implement a Graph type data-structure using a structure node of my own. The node will contain a node location (String), node desciption (as prompt, String) and a vector of pair of other node locations and their corresponding nodes structs.
The idea of the vector is to contain the adjacent node, and the adjacent node's location (String). 
Here is the structure definition:-

```
struct node
{
    string location;
    string prompt;
    vector<pair<string,node>> op;
    void insertNode(const node &b);
    void printAll();
};

void node::insertNode(const node &b)
{   
    op.push_back({b.location,b});
}

void node::printAll()
{   
    cout<<"\n"<<location<<": "<<this;
    cout<<"\n"<<prompt;
    for(int i=0;i<op.size();i++)
    {
        cout<<"\n"<<i+1<<". "<<op[i].first<<": "<<&op[i].second;
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
```

As a test, I decided to make a graph. Below is the main() function.

```
int main()
{
    vector<node> nodes;
    nodes.resize(5);

    nodes[0].location = "point1";
    nodes[0].prompt = "This is point1"; 
    nodes[1].location = "point2";
    nodes[1].prompt = "This is point2";
    nodes[2].location = "point3";
    nodes[2].prompt = "This is point3";
    nodes[3].location = "point4";
    nodes[3].prompt = "This is point4";
    nodes[4].location = "point5";
    nodes[4].prompt = "This is point5";

    nodes[0].insertNode(nodes[1]);
    nodes[0].insertNode(nodes[2]);
    nodes[1].insertNode(nodes[0]);
    nodes[1].insertNode(nodes[2]);
    nodes[1].insertNode(nodes[3]);
    nodes[2].insertNode(nodes[0]);
    nodes[2].insertNode(nodes[1]);
    nodes[2].insertNode(nodes[4]);
    nodes[3].insertNode(nodes[1]);
    nodes[3].insertNode(nodes[4]);
    nodes[4].insertNode(nodes[2]);
    nodes[4].insertNode(nodes[3]);

    for(int i=0;i<nodes.size();i++) 
        cout<<&nodes[i]<<endl;  

    for(int i=0;i<nodes.size();i++) 
        nodes[i].printAll();    
    return 0;
}
```

And this is the output I am getting. The issue is the struct addresses when the insertNode() function is called is the same as the address when defined in the main() function. But the struct addresses change when I call the printAll() function. I want to access adjacent nodes via the current node. Something like: node[0].op[0].second.printAll(); but since the memory addresses are different, I am receiving a NULL memory.

```
/*
0xfb1630
0xfb1688
0xfb16e0
0xfb1738
0xfb1790

point1: 0xfb1630
This is point1
1. point2: 0xfb1890
2. point3: 0xfb1908

point2: 0xfb1688
This is point2
1. point1: 0xfb5ea0
2. point3: 0xfb5f18
3. point4: 0xfb5f90

point3: 0xfb16e0
This is point3
1. point1: 0xfb6400
2. point2: 0xfb6478
3. point5: 0xfb64f0

point4: 0xfb1738
This is point4
1. point2: 0xfb6760
2. point5: 0xfb67d8

point5: 0xfb1790
This is point5
1. point3: 0x6325b0
2. point4: 0x632628
*/
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. My assumption is there must be a mistake in the memory address passed in the function, which is currently passing by reference. But if I change the node inside the pair into a node pointer, then the compiler return "wrong 2nd argument". 
What is wrong with the approach? Improvements regarding the code (which may deviate from the original question) are welcome as well.

Comment: Why are you concerned with the address of these items?  I see nothing wrong with the code as-is.

Comment: Thought it was iterator invalidation, but no, it looks like plain old copying. If you are coming in from Java or C#, you may be surprised to learn that C++ defaults to using values rather than references. If you want to use and store references you have to ask for them.

Comment: If you want pointers, `vector<pair<string,node>> op;` becomes `vector<pair<string,node*>> op;` and `op.push_back({b.location,b});` becomes `op.push_back({b.location,&b});`. This would be an answer, but Like @PaulMcKenzie , I'm not sure exactly what you want here.

Comment: Also, for a graph data structure represented by a C++ program, there is little to no need to know the address of anything.  If the container(s) are set up correctly, a graph can use simple value semantics.

Comment: standard containers store copies. You compare memory adresses of different objects

Comment: @user4581301 I apologize if my intent seems unclear, I am fairly new to pointers and it is difficult for me to even identify the problem.
All I want is to access some other node via a current node. 
eg -> if my current node is A, and the node B is adjacent to A. I want to be able to access node B's member variables/functions via node A. 
Which should be something like `A.op[0].second.printAll()` (consider node B is the first option in the _options_ vector)

As the provided output shows, if I am accessing some other node via the current node, it is pointing me to the wrong location.

Comment: @kkfatlegs -- Then maybe your `std::vector<pair<string, node>>` should be `std::vector<std::pair<string, std::shared_ptr<node>>>;`?  Then you create nodes using `node = std::make_shared<node>();` and use that as the `second` of the pair.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are storing discrete `node` objects in your `vector`, not pointers (addresses) to objects. This is why you get different addresse when printing the `this` pointer.

```
void node::insertNode(const node &b)
{   
    op.push_back({b.location,b});//<-- here, you make a copy of b and store it in op
}
```

If you want to work with pointers, declare your variables accordingly:

```
struct node
{
    string location;
    string prompt;
    vector<pair<string,const node*>> op;//<-- pair of string and pointer to node
    void insertNode(const node &b);
    void printAll();
};

void node::insertNode(const node &b)
{   
    op.push_back({b.location,&b});//<-- insert address of b
}

void node::printAll()
{   
    cout<<"\n"<<location<<": "<<this;
    cout<<"\n"<<prompt;
    for(int i=0;i<op.size();i++)
    {
        cout<<"\n"<<i+1<<". "<<op[i].first<<": "<<op[i].second;//<-- no need for `&` anymore
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
```

Edited to add the `const` as per comments

Comment: Right to an extend but main thing here is main vector called " vector<node> nodes;" is declared inside main function and has a local scope withing this function only. Passing address of object allocated in this vector results in passing address of locally created objects. For this to work  properly you need to allocate node objects on heap.

Comment: @melk That's exactly what I tried last time. It is giving me matching function call error.
 

error: no matching function for call to 'std::vector<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, node*> >::push_back(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)'
  op.push_back({b.location,&b});

Comment: @kkfatlegs It's the `const` in `const node &b` that's getting you. You cannot assign a `const` pointer to a non-`const` pointer because then some fool could use the non-`const` pointer to change a value that you promised would not be changed. Sorry I didn't spot that when I commented above. Either `vector<pair<string,node>> op;` needs to be `vector<pair<string,const node *>> op;` or you have to lose the `const` in  `void node::insertNode(const node &b)` Try for the first option. It's usually best to start with the most restrictive option and loosen up only if forced to.

Comment: @user4581301 The const was the issue, it is working now. Thank you

Comment: @kkfatlegs The issue with this is that all of those pointers must have lifetimes equal to or longer than the lifetime of the node that it is being added to.  The better way to do this is to redesign your code so that the entire graph is self-contained, and not relying on pointers declared outside of the graph.  You build the graph up, then it doesn't matter if the variables declared to build the graph will exist or not -- the graph should have all the information contained in it.  The problem is that you don't have a real graph class, only a node class.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie What do you mean by a self-contained graph? And regarding the graph class, my next step was going to be that. My graph class was going to use the above defined structure to contain an entire graph in itself. But that is just going to build up on the existing code, what suggestions do you propose? Any topics that I should refer?

Comment: What I mean is what you mentioned.  Create a `graph` class that has all of the node information inside of it as member variables.  Then there are no scoping issues, pointers remain where they are since the variables can't go out of scope until the graph goes out of scope, etc.  The entire issue you were having has to deal with taking a shortcut in having a half-implemented "graph class", where all the guts are in the `main` program.  That won't work -- if you had done the graph class first, you more than likely would never had encountered the problem.